# How can I Assign a applet

Tags: java, applet

Following this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html), i'm on the step 7, and I don't understand what to do in `PolicyTool`. I need that to assign my applet in my application, because when I run my applet I got a `SecurityException` with the following error message:

```
Could not open file policy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\raystore: 
sun.security.provider.PolicyParser$ParsingException line 1: expected [;] found[pípí]
```

Comment: Could not open file policy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\raystore: sun.security.provider.PolicyParser$ParsingException line 1: expected [;] found[pípí]

Comment: Policy files are not a solution to giving trust to an applet when deployed, so you might as well digitally sign the applet now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a file, and its contents are apparently causing a problem:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\raystore

When you generate the key

```
keytool -import -alias company -file 
        CompanyCer.cer -keystore 
    raystore -storepass abcdefgh
```

Double check that it actually generated a file in the same location.

Then,

```
keystore "/home/ray/raystore"; // make sure you reference the path to the key you generated in the previous step

// A sample policy file that lets a program 
// create demo.ini in user's home directory
// Satya N Dodda

grant SignedBy "company" {
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission 
    "user.home", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission 
    "${user.home}/demo.ini", "write";
};
```

**Edit:**

Generate key

```
keytool -genkey -keystore mykeys -storepass abc123
```

Sign jar

```
jarsigner -keystore mykeys -storepass abc123 app.jar johndoe
```

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Comment: Where I type keystore "my path" ?, I don't understand this.